# Angular 5 child module not seeing providers

Tags: angular, module, angular2-routing, provider, resolver

I've create a child module for my application with child routes but whenever I add a resolver to my child route it complains about my resolver not being provided, but it is provided.

**My sub-module**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: SubTypesComponent,
        resolve: {
            contact: 'contact'
        }
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
    ],
    declarations: [SubTypesComponent],
    providers: [
        SubTypeService,
        {
            provide: 'contact',
            useValue: () => {
                return {
                    id: 1,
                    name: 'Some Contact',
                    website: 'http://some.website.com'
                };
            }
        }
    ]
})
export class TermModule {
}
```

**The error I'm getting when I'm surfing to the route**

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[contact]: 
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[contact]: 
NullInjectorError: No provider for contact! 
_NullInjector.prototype.get@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1208:19 resolveToken@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1506:17 tryResolveToken@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1448:16 StaticInjector.prototype.get@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1316:20 resolveToken@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1506:17 tryResolveToken@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1448:16 StaticInjector.prototype.get@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:1316:20 resolveNgModuleDep@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:11061:12 NgModuleRef_.prototype.get@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:12294:16 PreActivation.prototype.getToken@webpack-internal:///../../../router/esm5/router.js:4057:16 PreActivation.prototype.getResolver@webpack-internal:///../../../router/esm5/router.js:4040:41 PreActivation.prototype.resolveNode@webpack-internal:///../../../router/esm5/router.js:4015:88 PreActivation.prototype.runResolve@webpack-internal:///../../../router/esm5/router.js:3991:84 PreActivation.prototype.resolveData/runningChecks$<@webpack-internal:///../../../router/esm5/router.js:3630:162 MergeMapSubscriber.prototype._tryNext@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js:133:22 MergeMapSubscriber.prototype._next@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js:123:13 MergeMapSubscriber.prototype.notifyComplete@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/operators/mergeMap.js:175:13 InnerSubscriber.prototype._complete@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/InnerSubscriber.js:34:9 Subscriber.prototype.complete@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:122:13 Subscriber.prototype._complete@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:140:9 Subscriber.prototype.complete@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:122:13 Subscriber.prototype._complete@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:140:9 Subscriber.prototype.complete@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:122:13 Subscriber.prototype._complete@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:140:9 Subscriber.prototype.complete@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:122:13 Subscriber.prototype._complete@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:140:9 Subscriber.prototype.complete@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:122:13 Subscriber.prototype._complete@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:140:9 Subscriber.prototype.complete@webpack-internal:///../../../../rxjs/_esm5/Subscriber.js:122:13 onLoad@webpack-internal:///../../../http/esm5/http.js:1630:21 ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:421:17 onInvokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4938:24 ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:420:17 Zone.prototype.runTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:188:28 ZoneTask.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:496:24 invokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:1517:9 globalZoneAwareCallback@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:1543:17 Stack trace: resolvePromise@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:809:31 resolvePromise@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:775:17 scheduleResolveOrReject/<@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:858:17 ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:421:17 onInvokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../core/esm5/core.js:4938:24 ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:420:17 Zone.prototype.runTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:188:28 drainMicroTaskQueue@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:595:25 ZoneTask.invokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:500:21 invokeTask@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:1517:9 globalZoneAwareCallback@webpack-internal:///../../../../zone.js/dist/zone.js:1543:17
```

The child route is also imported in my main modules routing, this works because when I remove this resolver from my child route I can navigate to the route without any problems.

I've done this many times without any problems so I'm kind of lost here.

**My parent routing**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule} from '@angular/common';
import {Routes} from '@angular/router';
import {routes as subTypeRoutes} from '../term/term.module';

export const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'subtypes',
        resolve: {
            project: ProjectResolve
        },
        children: subTypeRoutes
    },
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule
    ],
    declarations: []
})
export class ProjectRoutingModule {
}
```

**My parent module**

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
    ],
    declarations: [
        ProjectsComponent,
    ],
    providers: [
        ProjectService,
        ProjectsResolve,
        ProjectResolve
    ]
})
export class ProjectModule {
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the source of the AppModule and of the AppRoutingModule please?

Comment: @JeanPaulA. I've added the parent module and it's routing, these are separated files. I also removed all the other stuff because I've similar child modules that work exactly the same and follow the same setup structure, but they do work though

Comment: You certainly have to export your resolver so it can be used in the AppRoutingModule

Comment: @PierreMallet But I've never exported a resolver from my other routes and they do work though...

Comment: yes but did the route "définition" and the route "usage" were in different modules? You contact resolver is registered in  TermModule and you are using your route in the ProjectRoutingModule which don't have any link to you provided contact injectable. I don't see how that could work.

Comment: @PierreMallet You've put me on the right track, I think I've found it. Testing some more but I'll post an answer with a reference to your comment after I did some validation

Comment: @PierreMallet posted the answer, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment of @PierreMallet I've found it. 
I had to import the `TermModule` in my `ParentModule`. This seems pretty normal, but the reason I overlooked this was because lately I've been developing a lot`GrandChildModules` and I did not had to directly import it in my `ParentModule` because it was imported via the `ChildModule` so I forgot about that part.

ParentModule > ChildModule > GrandChildModule

The complex setup of the project structure made me overlook this.